# While using aws cognito google federated login in my Angular ionic app , after login it does not retrun to the app from aws auth domain

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, authentication, ionic-framework, google-cloud-platform

I use aws cognito google federated login in my Angular ionic app. While login process it go to aws cognito auth url , after authentication complete , it does not redirect to app!, in cognito it request only redirect urls so i put this ("http://localhost:8100/home-shop") home url, but it is now working!

it showing the following error message!:
"An error was encountered with the requested page."

Is it possible to add aws cognito  google federated login in angular ionic app?!